# Finding the summation of $c_i$ for $c_i=\begin{cases}i &\quad\text{if $i-1$ is exact power of $2$ }\\1&\quad\text{otherwise.}\\ \end{cases}$

Tags: functions, summation, upper-lower-bounds

While reading the text Introduction to Algorithms by Cormen et. al. I came across a few mathematical step which I felt like proving in a more detailed manner, as I could not get steps of the mathematics which they did in short.

Below is the excerpt from the text.

> $$c_i = \begin{cases}
>         i &\quad\text{if $i-1$ is an exact power of $2$ }\\
>        1&\quad\text{otherwise.}\\
> \end{cases}$$
>
> So,
>
> $$\sum_{i=1}^{n}c_i\leq n+\sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor lg(n) \rfloor}2^j\tag 1$$
> $$<n+2n=3n$$

---

The following is my attempt to understand the step $(1)$

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}c_i=\sum_{\text{$i-1$ is a power of 2}}c_i +\sum_{\text{$i-1$ is not a power of 2}}c_i $$

$$=\sum_{\text{$j$ is a power of 2}}(j+1) +\sum_{\text{$j$ is not a power of 2}}(1) ,\quad\quad\text{where $j=i-1$}$$

$$=\sum_{\text{$j$ is a power of 2}}(j) +\sum_{\forall j}(1) = \left (\sum_{\text{$j$ is a power of 2}}j\right )+n \tag 2$$

$$\text{where $0\leq j \leq n-1$}$$

for the situation in which $j$ is power of $2$ let $2^k$ be the maximum possible value of $j$. So,

$$2^k=n-1 \implies k=\lfloor \log_2(n-1) \rfloor$$

Now we know,

$$n-1<n \implies \log_2(n-1)<\log_2(n) \implies \lfloor\log_2(n-1)\rfloor\leq\lfloor\log_2(n)\rfloor \tag3$$

Let $j=2^t$ , $t=0$ to $k$

So from $(2)$ and $(3)$ we have,

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}c_i\leq n+\sum_{t=0}^{\lfloor lg(n) \rfloor}2^t \tag 4$$

The step which the authors achieved directly in $(1)$ took me so many steps to understand or derive in $(4)$. Is there a shorter method available or some intuition which the authors used to achieve the result directly?

Comment: I did not get you

Comment: I jumped the step, substituted $c_i$ with $i$ or $1$ and then changed the variables to $j$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $i-1=2^j$, where $i\le n$ then $j=\lg(i-1)<\lg n$. Moreover, $j$ is an integer, so $j\le\lfloor\lg n\rfloor$. Thus, each term of $\sum_{i=1}^nc_i$ is either $1$ or $2^j+1$ for some $j$ such that $0\le j\le\lfloor\lg n\rfloor$. Thus, we automatically get a contribution of $1$ from each of the $n$ terms, for a total of $n$. We get another $2^j$ for the terms with $0\le j\le\lfloor\lg n\rfloor$, which contribute

$$\sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor\lg n\rfloor}2^j=2^{\lfloor\lg n\rfloor+1}-1<2\cdot2^{\lg n}=2n\;.$$

Thus,

$$\sum_{i=1}^nc_i\le n+\sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor\lg n\rfloor}2^j<n+2n=3n\;.$$

Comment: $\text{lg}=\log_2$?

Comment: @UmbQbify-Key20-: Yes; it’s a standard abbreviation. (And you can get it with `\lg`.)

Comment: Specifically for base 2 logarithm? Thanks!

Comment: @UmbQbify-Key20-: Yes, specifically for the binary log.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thanks for the help.

Comment: I felt like asking a little thing, You said that in $\sum_{i=1}^{n} c_i$ , $c_i$ is either $1$ or $2^j$, but as per the definition, should not it be $1$ or $2^j+1$. If I am mistaken pls rectify me. :)

Comment: @AbhishekGhosh: Oops!  You’re absolutely right, and I need to change the answer slightly. Thanks! (Because I can’t see the question when I’m typing an answer, I sometimes lose track of details.)